# Build tools for Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, build, gulp

just wondering if there are any build tools similar to Gulp for Node that I can use for Google App Engine?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use whatever frontend build tools you'd like with App Engine. Simply use Gulp or your favorite tool to compile/copy your final frontend files into a folder that you expose as a resource directory in your `app.yaml` (in the case of Python, Go, or PHP) or your `appengine-web.xml` (in the case of Java).

Take a look at the Python docs, for example, for [Using Static Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles).

If you're talking about invoking App Engine's command line tools from Gulp (i.e. if you wanted to do something like `gulp deploy` and have it push your app to App Engine), you can do that via a plugin like [gulp-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell).

In our codebase, we use Gulp with App Engine Java. It works great!

Comment: Hi, I am building web application using angular js + java servlets + gulp. I wanna integrate google appengine. But I dont wanna go with Eclipse. I need to use web service calls too. guide me which one suit for me and how to do it.